# use a remote server during the development of app on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

have a computer with COM ports, installed tomcat server. is it possible to use it as a remote server for developing Web applications which used the com port. 
particularly interested in debugging.
Thanks.

Comment: yes. AFAIK, All the IDEs support debugging of a remote servers including web servers.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://en.newinstance.it/2005/10/04/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse/) a tutorial to remote debug a tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

Java debugging usually go over a network connection.  If all you have is a serial port (which is what COM port provides) then you must get a TCP/IP network up over serial FIRST.  This is usually done with PPP or SLIP which is a quite interesting exercise in itself.